# How to increment a float by lowest zero

Tags: javascript, math

I have a float x that can be any size and need to increment its amount by 1 on the last zero, so .1 for 1.0, .01 for 2.00, etc.

The following code works for certain numbers, but not all:

*Javascript*

```
let a = "0".repeat(floatNumber.length-2)+'1';
let position = floatNumber.indexOf(".");
let add = [a.slice(0, position), ".", a.slice(position)].join('');
```

1.1 becomes 1.2.

but

10.1 becomes 10.20. I need an output of 10.2.

Comment: Do you need output like 10.2 rather than 10.20?

Comment: `jquery` and `math` tags? [Really?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssRUr.gif)

Comment: @VLAZ It has nothing to do with jQuery, but math seems appropriate.

Comment: @JLRishe (that was the joke)

Comment: @VLAZ Ah, I didn't notice the link.

Comment: I still don't get it, `increment its amount by 1 on the last zero` then `.1 for 1.0` and `.01 for 2.00` and `10.1 becomes 10.2` seem to me like 3 different things. so which one is it?

Comment: When there is a dot, the length gets increased.

Comment: @JonasWilms so in other words, when there is a dot, you simply append the digit `"1"` to the number? That doesn't sound right. My issue here is, what is the difference between `2`, `2.0`, `2.00` and for example `0000002` or `2.000000`? mathematically they are all the same value/float so what is the last zero in these? If `2.00` is supposed to be incremented by `0.01` then why is `10.1` not incremented by `1.0` as there is the last `0` I can see? Or by `0.01` as this would be the first zero at the end. Why is it supposed to be `10.2`? I don't get the rules.

Comment: What happens for "0.09"? "0.10"? "0.1" something else?

Comment: Dood's answer is exactly what i needed. @VLAZ; sorry my first post on stackoverflow, added jquery tag as i am using the library in the program anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your code, it is working fine to add I used `parseFloat` , so I guess may be you are missing it as you haven't added that part of code.

**MODIFIED:**

I have modified the snippet as it didn't support some of the numbers. now it will give your desired output..

```js
function floatNum(floatNumber){
  
  let position = floatNumber.indexOf(".");
  if(position == -1){
    return +floatNumber+1;
  } else {
    let len = floatNumber.length;
    let a = "0".repeat(len-2)+'1';
    let dec = len-position-1;
    let add = [a.slice(0, position), ".", a.slice(position)].join('');
    return (parseFloat(floatNumber) + parseFloat(add)).toFixed(dec);
  }
}
console.log(floatNum('0.01'))
console.log(floatNum('10.12'))
console.log(floatNum('1'))
console.log(floatNum('123'))
```

Comment: Yes can you run my snippet, it gives the output as `10.23`

Comment: Agreed. I didn't saw this answer before posting mine, but yours is definitely more correct than the highest voted one. I would just add a safe-guard against integers input which will break your logic (e.g `floatNum("123")` => `"123.100"`) and against less than 2 length inputs (e.g floatNum("1") => RangeError).

Comment: @Kaiido Thanks for the explanation, I'm trying to fix those

Comment: @Kaiido fixed the changes

Comment: Good enough for me ;-) (but since these were edge cases, I guess your prior example inputs where actually better for the current question)

Comment: Perfect! This is exactly the input > output i need. Thanks a heap Dood.

Answer (score 1):

You could just take + increase the last digit:

```
    const result = input.slice(0, -1) + (+input[input.length - 1] + 1);
```

Comment: perfect and simple.+1

Comment: "0.09" => "0.010" not sure it's what OP wants.

Comment: Close, but no cigar. As Kaiido notes, it increases the notation size.